# apt-get wait for lock release

Tags: apt, lock

If you are running `apt-get` commands on terminal and want to install stuff on the software center, the center says it waits until `apt-get` finishes. I wanted to know if it is possible to do the same but on the terminal, i.e., make `apt-get` on the terminal wait until the lock is released.

I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running), that uses `aptdcon` to install stuff. I would like to know if:

- Is it really not possible to do with `apt-get`?
- Is `aptdcon` compatible with `apt-get`, i.e., can I use both to install stuff without borking the system?

Comment: does apt-get not notify you if you operate in the software center?

Comment: What do you mean notify?

Comment: if you run `apt-get <some command>` in the terminal, it will tell you that a different process is locking the package database (e.g. the software center is operating). So the system should already behave like you want it.

Comment: `apt-get` has no built-in functionality for this purpose.

Comment: You should consider choosing this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277255/3285 as it's fixed now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## `apt` 1.9.11

This was solved in [Debian bug #754103](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754103) in [this commit](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/merge_requests/109/diffs?commit_id=93e1565796b61eb44bec39f50e09a34cbe090178). The fix is in versions of apt newer than 1.9.11.

> - apt(8): Wait for lock (Closes: [#754103](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=754103))

You can enable this option by setting `-o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=60` as an argument to `apt` or `apt-get`. Where `60` is the time to wait in seconds for the lock.

```
apt -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=60 install FOO
apt-get -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=60 install FOO
```

You can test this by running two identical commands and simply not answering immediately on the first one to *`Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`*? On the second command you run, it'll tell you,

> Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`. It is held by process 946299 (apt)

Comment: It is fixed in apt version 1.9.11, newer of which is available e.g. in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Note that only `apt` has this feature, not `apt-get`.

Comment: I've updated this answer to reflect the comment by @jarno and the ticket you linked.

Comment: As of apt 2.4.10, on Ubuntu 22.04, this DOES NOT WORK FOR "update". It works for "apt(-get) upgrade", but if you run two "update" at the same time one of them will still fail instead of waiting.

Answer (score 9):

(Repasting from [Ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1371734/26436))

There is now an option built into `apt-get` that lets you wait for the other apt to finish.

Use the `DPkg::Lock::Timeout` option to set a timeout, in seconds, for an apt-get command. This example will wait for 60 seconds:

```bsh
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=60 install packagename
```

If you set that value to -1, it will keep waiting forever.

```bsh
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=-1 install packagename
```

For more information see: [Waiting for apt locks without the hacky bash scripts](https://blog.sinjakli.co.uk/2021/10/25/waiting-for-apt-locks-without-the-hacky-bash-scripts/).  This option was [added to `apt-get` in Feb 2020](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/merge_requests/109).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this already:

create a new script called apt-get (wrapper for apt-get) in the

> /usr/local/sbin

directory with the following bash code inside:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#Make sure there is no space before the hashbang above!
i=0 
tput sc 
while fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
     case $(($i % 4)) in
         0 ) j="-" ;;
         1 ) j="\\" ;;
         2 ) j="|" ;;
         3 ) j="/" ;;
     esac
     tput rc
     echo -en "\r[$j] Waiting for other software managers to finish..." 
     sleep 0.5
     ((i=i+1)) 
done
/usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/apt-get
```

run it.
run it again with synaptic or another apt-get open. ;)

`/usr/local/sbin` comes earlier in the path...

I think it could cause chaos with scripts somewhere... maybe?

Comment: Should probably acknowledge the author: https://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running

Comment: It did not work in my case.. I got: `[/] Waiting for other software managers to finish...E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`

Answer (score 0):

For people who are using the older version (< 1.9.11) the above-mentioned methods might not work so here is my hacky version of the solution.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

timeout=12
wait_time=5
counter=0

while (( counter < timeout )); do
    if sudo apt install jq -y 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "jq installed successfully."
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Installation failed. Waiting for other software managers to finish..."
        sleep $wait_time
        ((counter++))
    fi
done

echo "Could not install jq within $((timeout * wait_time)) seconds. Skipping installation."
```

and here is a minified version too

```bash
for i in {1..12}; do sudo apt install jq -y && exit 0 || sleep 5; done
```